# How to create self instantiating views in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Currently I just instantiate the view directly below the definition, but I was wondering if there is a better way to do this ?

```
var BVApp = Backbone.View.extend({
    Name: 'BVApp',
    // do chonka stuff
});
$A.Class.add(new BVApp());
```

Comment: Could you please add what you do not like and why? Backbone objects have to be instantiated using `new` - do you expect leaving the `new` away?

Comment: Well, you could write a wrapper called `Backbone.ViewAuto` that instantiates automatically in probably a few lines of code for one.

Comment: Are four chars `new ` too much for you to type or whats the intent? Note: I don't see a generic way to "instantiate" that is shorter than `new`. So, if it's really a matter of code length: don't bother.

Comment: I like all my code in the brackets. I don't care about the typing.  But that is a bonus too, 1 less line of code.

Comment: did you have a look at this http://marionettejs.com/

Comment: @nikhil - no, I know it is dependent on Backbone but I'm actually using just a basic class system which is actually in the opposite direction - a lower abstraction level.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to create a "self instantiating view" per se (since you have to instantiate it somewhere, somehow!), but there may be a way to achieve what you want.  Depending on your specific goals I see two ways to get around having to explicitly instantiate your object:

1. Create a method that instantiates and adds your view:

   ```
   $A.Class.addInstantiated = function (ObjectConstructor) {
       this.add(new ObjectConstructor());
   };
   ```
2. If what you want is a singleton, and you're using a module loader like RequireJS, then you can actually just return an instantiated object:

   ```
   define([], function () {
       function Foo(a) {
           // ...does stuff...
       }

       return new Foo();
   });
   ```

   This way every use of your module will be the same, instantiated object.  One downside of this approach is that it isn't particularly testable, but you can get around this by having your uninstantiated model in one module and then instantiate it as a singleton in a second module.  E.g.:

   ```
   define([], function () {
       function Foo(a) {
           // ...does stuff...
       }

       return Foo;
   });

   define(['foo'], function (Foo) {
       return new Foo();
   });
   ```